# JQGRID return all cell values from row in serializeCellData

Tags: jqgrid

Im looking for a way to return all of the rows data in the post element every time the user edits a cell.

Currently i have

```js
serializeCellData: function( postdata ) 
{
    postdata[site.csrf.keys.name]  = site.csrf.name;
    postdata[site.csrf.keys.value] = site.csrf.value;
    postdata['po_id'] = id_po;

    postdata['product_code'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'product_code');
    postdata['description'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'description');
    postdata['account_code'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'account_code');
    postdata['qty'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'qty');
    postdata['price_each'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'price_each');
    postdata['gst_each'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'gst_each');
    postdata['price_total'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'price_total');
    postdata['gst_total'] = $("#order_details_grid").jqGrid('getCell',irowsel,'gst_total');
    return postdata; 
},
```

and it mostly works. However the one cell that i have just edited is returned as html.

I could change the controller to take in the post name as well as value so it can be more universal code. However at this stage i just want to pass every value.

the code wont be used alot so performance isnt a huge consideration at this point.

is there an easy way to get the value of the cell while in edit and not the html?

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the information about the version of jqGrid and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use (can use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use `beforeSubmitCell` instead of `serializeCellData` to extend the information, which will be send to the server. The first parameter of `beforeSubmitCell` is the `rowid` and the return value should be the object with additional properties. For example,

```js
beforeSubmitCell: function (rowid) {
    return $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
}
```

Additionally, I'd recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Starting with the version 4.14.0 the methods `getCell` and `getRowData` can read successfully data from editing cells.

Comment: Oleg thanks for that. I am already using jqgrid free just not the latest version.